# Lasting gravity-free vacuum on the Earth

Tags: gravity, vacuum

As the title says, Is it possible to create a lasting gravity-free vacuum here on Earth?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"?  Long-lasting, perhaps ?

Comment: What is a "gravity-free vacuum"? Are you under the impression that we can build an equivalent of Faraday cages for gravity?

Comment: Do you mean a volume of space that is without gravity on Earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been no successful tests done on any sort of gravity shielding method or device. In the 1990s, Eugene Podkletnov claimed that he was able to block a small percentage of gravity using a rotating disk composed of superconducting ceramic material.   He said:  "Someone in the laboratory was smoking a pipe, and the pipe smoke rose in a column above the superconducting disc. So we placed a ball-shaped magnet above the disc, attached to a balance. The balance behaved strangely. We substituted a nonmagnetic material, silicon, and still the balance was very strange. We found that any object above the disc lost some of its weight, and we found that if we rotated the disc, the effect was increased."
However, others have attempted to duplicate this test with no success, so it is rightfully questioned.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Podkletnov

Answer (score 0):

It's not physically possible.  For there to be no gravity- that is, no measurable gravitational force or acceleration in a container- the container must be in free fall; which means that it must be moving.  In orbit the container would be in free fall.  If a tunnel could be dug straight through the Earth's axis and the container dropped down the tunnel, the container could oscillate up and down in the tunnel, always in free fall.  But even in those cases, there would be micro-gravity effects related to the tidal effect: very slight non-uniformities in the gravitational field that could be detected.  Whether or not there is a vacuum in the container is irrelevant.